# Select a prop of an object with arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I have this data coming from a REST API in JSON. I'll put here as an example.

```
var JsonCategoriaHot = {
    "products": [
        {"id": 8,
         "id_manufacturer": "0",
         "manufacturer_name": "Fashion Manufacturer",
         "id_supplier": "0",
         "id_category_default": "Isso terá de ser uma URL ou um nome",
         "new": "null",
         "images": "ur.presta.com",
         "name": [{"id": "1", "value": "Printed Summer Dress"},
                  {"id": "2", "value": "Vestido estampado de verão"}],
         "description": [{"id":"1","value":"Ensaio do Muzenza"}],},
        {"id":1}, // just empty data to represent "something"
        {"id":2},
        {"id":3},
        {"id":4},
        {"id":5},
        {"id":9,
         "name": "Michel Conrado",
         "images": "ur.presta.com/michelconrado",
         "manufacturer_name": "Muzenza",
         "category_default": "mudar de cat_default para url",
         "description": "Essa é uma descrição"
        },
        {"id":12,
         "name": "12 Michel Conrado",
         "images": "ur.presta.com/michelconrado",
         "manufacturer_name": "Muzenza",
         "category_default": "mudar de cat_default para url",
         "description": "Essa é uma descrição"
        }
    ]
};
```

So from this data I want to map some objects. And change some strings name. With this code below:

```
var idparaurl = JsonCategoriaHot.products.map(function(products,i) {
    return {
        index: i + 1,
        name: products.name,
        image:  products.images,
        fabricante: products.manufacturer_name,
        catgdf: products.id_category_default,
        desc: products.description,
    };
});
```

Now I need to "select" the property "name" choosing a default id for this case will be "Products" > "Name" > ID > 2 > value > String.

It's like a "reduce" and choose a value from the "name" array.

Maybe in the future will be more languages to support. So Each ID represents an translation from my CMS for each correspond languages.

It should return (for each object - all mapped data will come like this):

```
[
    {
        "catgdf": "Isso terá de ser uma URL ou um nome tidpo Muzenza",
        "image": "ur.presta.com",
        "index": 1,
        "name":  "Vestido estampado de verão",
        "desc": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "value": "Ensaio do Muzenza"
            }
        ],
        "fabricante": "Fashion Manufacturer"
    }

    //...
]
```

The "description" array I will apply this solution also so I should be like this inside the obj:

```
    //...
    "desc": "Ensaio do Muzenza"
}
```

Comment: Does the map iterate the objects ?

Comment: hi! Raj Nathani just solved my situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a `filter` operation as opposed to using a `reduce`.

Here is a function which would work:

```
function parseArrayKeyIndexValue(valArray, id) {
  if (!(valArray instanceof Array)) {
    return valArray;
  }
  return valArray.filter(function(valArrayItem){
    if (valArrayItem.id === id) {
      return true;
    }
  })[0].value;
}
```

The map in your example would look like this:

```
var idparaurl = JsonCategoriaHot.products.map(function(products,i) {
    return {
        index: i + 1,
        name: parseArrayKeyIndexValue(products.name, "2"),
        image:  products.images,
        fabricante: products.manufacturer_name,
        catgdf: products.id_category_default,
        desc: parseArrayKeyIndexValue(products.description, "1"),
    };
});
```

The code can be run with your provided 'JsonCategoriaHot' example data at this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/zapimineje/edit?js,console,output

Comment: WoW! It works!!! Many Thanks! Sorry to be so newbie, I think this isn't a complex problem. I'm studying Javascript hard like 4 months.

you teach me a lot with this! thank you so much!